# How to get Spring web application work on Jboss?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, jboss

I feel like I have tried everything I could find but I can't find a way to make my spring app work on JBoss. 
I can get this to work fine with spring-boot:run by going to localhost:8080/create.

When I deploy the war to my JBoss server it won't work.
The console says that the web context is /webapp and I have tried localhost:8080/webapp/create and localhost:8080/webapp and it doesn't matter what I use, I get 404. Here is my code (edited for privacy)

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"Foo", "Foo"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

}
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

private static RestTemplate restTemplate;
private static final String jiraURL = "foo";
HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

@RequestMapping(value = "/create")
public String createIssue() {
    httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    String base64creds = "QjE5NDk4OkJ1QDJndDc0";
    httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64creds);
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Issue issue = new Issue();
    issue.setProject("foo");;
    issue.setSummary("foo");
    issue.setDescription("foo");
    issue.setIssueType("foo");
    issue.setAssignee("foo");
    String test = issue.toString();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(test, httpHeaders);
    try {
    HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(jiraURL, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
    System.out.println(response);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return "success";
}
}
```

Issue class is just a few fields and getters and setters

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.foo.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>
<description>REST API to aid in build process </description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <start-class>org.foo.webapp.Application</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: try once mentioning your context in application.properties and then access on jboss as localhost:8080/yourcontext/create

Comment: @AkshayKhopkar
I've tried adding a application.properties file with just 
"server.servlet-path= /*"
And I've also tried changing it to
"server.servlet-path= /buildevents"

Comment: try adding server.contextPath=/yourcontextpath

Comment: it didn't work, I'm going to just try resteasy. Thanks anyways!